# Is there a fluent way to do criteria queries in Fluent Nhibernate?

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

Currently I create my criteria as follows:

```
gameCriteria = Restrictions.Eq("Name", videoGameName);
```

I was wondering if fluent nhibernate adds any features that allow something of the following:

```
gameCriteria = Restrictions.Eq<VideoGame>(v => v.Name, videoGameName);
```

In short, I want to remove the *magic string*.  (My actual queries tend to involve many magic strings which lead to errors due to typos and such.)

Comment: Fluent NHibernate only deals with mappings, not queries.

Comment: I found the solution, but it may just be part of core NHibernate and nothing special involving Fluent NHibernate, which would be why my searching wasn't fruitful.

Answer (score 1):

Just found the answer in the repository that another developer wrote.

```
gameCriteria = Restrictions.Eq(Projections.Property<VideoGame>(v => v.Name), videoGameName);
```

Now I feel silly for the time I spent searching for this.

Comment: You could also use the QueryOver API or Query (LINQ) API for this

Answer (score 0):

There is a built in NHibernate class [Restrictions.cs](https://github.com/nhibernate/nhibernate-core/blob/master/src/NHibernate/Criterion/Restrictions.cs#L785). It provides this method:

```
/// <summary>
/// Build an ICriterion for the given property
/// </summary>
/// <param name="expression">lambda expression identifying property</param>
/// <returns>returns LambdaRestrictionBuilder</returns>
public static LambdaRestrictionBuilder On<T>(Expression<Func<T, object>> expression)
{
    ExpressionProcessor.ProjectionInfo projection = 
      ExpressionProcessor.FindMemberProjection(expression.Body);
    return new LambdaRestrictionBuilder(projection);
}
```

And we can use it like this:

```
// exact match
Restrictions.On<VideoGame>(v => v.Name == videoGameName);
```

or

```
// LIKE expression as 'videoGameName%'
Restrictions.On<VideoGame>(v => v.Name).IsLike(videoGameName, MatchMode.Start);
```

Comment: Is there a significant difference between this and projections?

Comment: Would not say it is important. The Restrictions.On is simply built in ;) at the end it will generate the same SQL... The point is: what is built in, should be preferred ... because with every new version.. you can count on that ... and maybe NH 4 is coming ;)... *well, just wanted to show you how to...*